# Symbol created in unevaluated second argument of If

Tags: symbols, contexts

Apologies for the long question title, but I couldn't come up with something shorter to describe the following.
Starting with a clean session, there are no symbols in, let's say, `myContext`:

```
Names["myContext`*"]
(* {} *)
```

But if I now evaluated this If statement,

```
If[False, myContext`mySymbol = "value"]
```

all of the sudden `mySymbol` has been created in `myContext`:

```
Names["myContext`*"]
(* {"myContext`mySymbol"} *)
```

but, as expected, `mySymbol` doesn't have a value:

```
myContext`mySymbol
(* myContext`mySymbol *)
```

My question is twofold: why has `mySymbol` been created, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: this is probably related to how just mentioning a symbol appears to add it to the symbol list. If you run a line with just `blah`, `blah` is added as a symbol. i don't know what the purpose of that is. maybe it's to make Options symbols (such as `Automatic`) show up in black instead of blue

Comment: Symbols are added to the context at parsing stage, not evaluation. So just reading that line is sufficient to create it. This is why when you use functions from a package that is loaded inside a function or using initializations, you should use the full context name of the function so that the parsing stage creates it in the appropriate context. Otherwise, it leads to shadowing.

Comment: Teake, I've marked this question "already has an answer here."  Please take a look at that Q&A and let me know if anything remains unanswered.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5616966) and its answers

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, that Q&A and the above comments clarify everything.